# vb.net Application.DoEvents() function halt and crash application in windows vista

Tags: vb.net

i made an application for serial communication. for this application i need to set delay time. during this delay time i m doing some other task. So for those task i need to take back control from delay function, for this purpose i am unsing Doevents() function.Its work fine **On other OS (XP, Windows7 32/64-bit)**. But **Application.DoEvents()** function halt and crash in windows vista.So is there any solution

```
 Private Sub TimeDelay(ByVal DT As Integer)

    Dim StartTick As Integer
    StartTick = Environment.TickCount()
    While ((Environment.TickCount() - StartTick) <= DT)
         Application.DoEvents()
    End While
    'Application.DoEvents()

End Sub
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Ahh, **yet another** reason why you should **never** use `Application.DoEvents()`. What have we learned?

Comment: Uh, it often leads to buggy behavior. Like your app crashing. Or other tricky re-entrancy problems. It's not the solution, despite what you might see in your old VB 6 books. The only people that should ever use `DoEvents` are those that have a complete and thorough understanding of the Windows message handling model and threading. And those people wouldn't ever use it.

Comment: hmm. then how can avoid form from being iressponsive during delay time.

Comment: Reading the answers you've already received is a good start, particularly the ones that someone else strongly endorses, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728267/vb-net-application-doevents-function-halt-and-crash-application-in-windows-vist/6728408#6728408). You need to do your processing on a separate thread. The `BackgroundWorker` component makes it quite painless to do that from a .NET application. The sample code on MSDN is very good. You can almost literally copy and paste.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) component instead of calling `Application.DoEvents()`.

Comment: @cody I admit using the backgroundworker takes delegates out of the question. But what exactly is wrong with my answer below?

Comment: @Dasiths: I don't know. I guess it's fine. I honestly had no idea what it had to do with the question. Where did `SquareClass` come from? I can't find that in the original code. And naming variables with an `o` prefix is incredibly strange. My eyes just kind of glazed over. Seems far too complicated for a relatively simple and common problem. It looks like code you just pasted in from someone else's answer to another question.

Comment: @cody the thread completed event example is off MSDN actually. I put his code in the sub. Anyway thought your wording as "only correct answer" made me qurious as to why it was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Please try System.Threading.Thread.SpinWait(10) after the Application.DoEvents, it might work.

Comment: Waiting 10 spins is rougly the equivalent of 50 microseconds, and entirely depends on the CPU. That's 0,00001 second. Isn't it better to wait 1 millisecond, since the precision of the delay is at 1 millisecond too?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use DoEvents for this purpose.

Create a seperate thread to run the code you have provided. And use a call back (thread completed) to notify when the time has elapsed.

```
Imports System.Threading
Public Class Tester
    Shared WithEvents oSquare As SquareClass = New SquareClass()
    Public Shared Sub Main

        Dim t As Thread
        t = New Thread(AddressOf oSquare.TimeDelay)
        t.Start()

    End Sub
    Shared Sub SquareEventHandler() Handles oSquare.ThreadComplete
        Console.WriteLine("Completed")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class SquareClass
    Public DT As Integer = 5000 ' 5 seconds (edited thanks to Mathias)

    Public Event ThreadComplete()

 Public Sub TimeDelay()   

   Dim StartTick As Integer    
   StartTick = Environment.TickCount()    
   While ((Environment.TickCount() - StartTick) <= DT)    
        thread.sleep(1000)    
   End While   

 RaiseEvent ThreadComplete()
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You are adding this comment without knowing what he really wants. First of all, you are running a loop with no content in it. That is very time consuming in the time that you decide to wait. Furthermore, what if he wants to make a delay, and then execute later lines of code after the delay, while still making the UI responsive?

Comment: it does not, your really seems to lack any knowledge of how threads work. Th UI thread will remain functional until the thread is complete and the event fires.

Comment: that is indeed true, but the SECOND thread will use as many system resources as it can, while the loop is running. You should insert a System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1) in the while loop. I say YOU lack knowledge of how threads work. What you did was just to load all the work onto a different thread - it still consumes as much processing power.

Comment: The UI thread will remain functional until the thread is complete and the event fires. Any action that requires a call back while the UI remains active need to be done though threading. Please check your facts before dowvoting others.

Comment: Was the question about processing power? Your suggestion of just inserting a System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1) to his code does not in any way solve his problem.

Comment: Yes it does, because it has the System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents() AND a Sleep, to wait just 1 millisecond, which would solve it. His problem occurs because there's too much CPU load if not waiting between DoEvent(). So yes, his question was about CPU power, and yes, my suggestion solves the problem. Your suggestion solves it too, but makes a separate thread that takes as much CPU as it can, for the duration of the delay. That's all I am saying.

Comment: again takes as much CPU? how so when my loop only runs 5 times in 5 seconds while your runs 1000 times every second?

Comment: Dasiths, this is embarassing. First of all you are still calculating in milliseconds. Set DT to 5000 in your code, and it will wait for 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds). So maybe you didn't even test your own code.

Second of all, while I must admit it doesn't consume as much CPU as I had assumed, it doesn't solve his problem, since he most likely wants to be able to wait in the same method call, and not on a separate thread.

Comment: @Dasiths let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1559/discussion-between-mathias-lykkegaard-lorenzen-and-dasiths)

Comment: First of all that 5 needs to 5000, I indeed tested it and works. Which you haven't "while I must admit it doesn't consume as much CPU as I had assumed, most likely wants to be able to wait in the same method call" it is embarassing indeed. Atleast admit you were wrong. Again please see the term 'delegate method' in the context of threading.

Comment: Dasiths, it does indeed wait 1 second every time, but you must set DT to 5000 to wait for 5 seconds. Your code is still slightly wrong.

Comment: @mathias mate you can stil use something called a delegate to run the 'desired final code' in the same thread which invoked the thread containing the loop. Which is the 'PROPER' way to handle this situation anyway. Serial Communcation or IRC, threading and waiting for a call back is the way to go. You need to keep it seperate from the UI thread. I'm glad you saw my code was right. Please consider taking back the down vote.

Comment: THANKS FOR Dasiths and also for mathis for analyzing this code. I do not have good concept about threadings.i donot want to make my application went to sleep mode for specific time. I want that i can show any nvigational msg during this time delay. so that its ccreate problem when i omit doevents.

Comment: Dasiths, i try your code but this do not even do not let application for load that form and give exception and i receive this msg."{"Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure ".frmTest.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "Windows Projejt" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed."}"

Comment: as i share before that this application run smoothly on XP,Windows 7 64/32-bit but only make problem in vista

Comment: The error you are getting has nothing to do with the code. It seems like you haven't compiled the project properly.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting a "System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)" in the loop as well. It might happen because there are too many events pending for Windows to process, therefore ending in high CPU usage.

Sleeping 1 millisecond is very little (actually only 0,001 second). And it would decrease CPU usage dramatically as well, while still allowing the program to remain responsive.

The final code would be:

```
Private Sub TimeDelay(ByVal DT As Integer)

     Dim StartTick As Integer
     StartTick = Environment.TickCount()
     While ((Environment.TickCount() - StartTick) <= DT)
          Application.DoEvents()
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
     End While
     'Application.DoEvents()

End Sub
```

Try running this code:

```
TimeDelay(1000000)
```

You will notice that in the process, the program will consume almost 100% CPU with your code, but 0% with mine.

Comment: I think the cost of re-lunching the thread costs much performance than SpinWait as far as I know. So I think SpinWait is better for a sleep slim period such as 1ms.

Comment: SpinWait(10) as you suggested just most likely waits less than 1 millisecond, but there are no performance differences. Sleep(1) will wait 1 millisecond (0,001 second), and SpinWait(10) waits 10 spins. The duration of a spin depends on the type of CPU, and whether it is AMD or Intel. Therefore, you can't count on the duration of a spin either.

Comment: I think sleep(1) makes no differance at all. Atleast use 1000 miliseconds. Some old processors won't even run the loop in 1 mili second. Please try your code in a real life application before posting it.

Comment: 1000 milliseconds is 1 second, but as you can clearly see in the code, he is using GetTickCount which returns the amount of ticks. By using 1000 milliseconds, his smallest delay to wait would be 1 second. For this, the smallest delay to wait would be 1 millisecond, if he wants to. It depends on the precision of the desired delay. Also, instead of saying "I think it makes no difference", test it. I've tried having the same problem as Muhammed Hanif, and this works.

Comment: A loop without System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1) and just System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents() in it, will consume close to 100% CPU. With System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1) in it, it will consume nothing at all. So yes, it does help.

Comment: I think you are right, he doesn't want some result in the loop.

SpinWait() is not intended to replace Sleep(), but is rather made available as an advanced optimization technique. If you know that some resource your thread is waiting for will become available in the immediate future, it is potentially more efficient to spin and wait, instead of using either Sleep() or a synchronization object, because those force a thread context switch, which is one of the most expensive operations performed by the operating system.

Comment: @Mathias why would anyone want to have an application wait 1 mili second? The smallest unit he would want is a second. Atleast consider a real life example. You seem to lack experience in threading and how call backs work. Look up google if you need more pointers.

Comment: Dasith, I have seen many cases where waiting less than a second is useful. Besides, you are saying all this without knowing what he wants.

Howard, you may be right! I didn't catch that part. Still, I would say using SpinWait(10) is a bit too little, since approximately 50 spins is 1 microsecond (0,001) millisecond, or (0,000001) second.

Comment: @Mathias, look what his pupose for this is "serial communication" run my code and see if it takes up 100% CPU, if it does not please admit you were wrong and undo the downvote you so hastely made without any evidence.

Comment: my application is not very heavey and not comsuming alot of resources.but during serial communication need to make some delay, so this delay let application to halt on vista, if i comment doEvent, then application run fine on all OS. I added **System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1) **.even i change 1to 10. thismake app little stable but still same problem